# A phrase for "with no attached qualifier"

Tags: phrases

If an artist is described alternatively as "a pop artist," "a rock artist," or "a blues artist," but never as "an artist," that is, with no attached qualifier, what would be an acceptable / common / good way to describe this fact?

1/ "He is never called just 'an artist.'"

2/ "He is never called simply 'an artist.'"

3/ "He is never called 'an artist, period.'"

Other suggestions?

Comment: A song is never called *a* *genre*. Where have you seen that?

Comment: I had not realized it was a literal translation from my native language, where we do, to mean that it belongs to said genre. I edit my question.

Comment: [Bear in mind that the simple present is only for repeated stuff. So, "I'll edit my question."]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get what you're trying to say. I would this is best expressed this way:

> He is never just referred to as "an artist".

Each of your examples are problematic to a degree.

> 1 "He is never called just 'an artist.'"

Spoken, this could sound like "just an artist" are the words never said. I've placed the word 'just' earlier in the sentence to make that clear.

> 2 "He is never called simply 'an artist.'"

The use of "simply" is clearer, but has the same problem as with example 1.

> 3 "He is never called 'an artist, period.'"

The problem with this is that "period" (or in British English, "full stop") is idiomatically said at the end of a sentence in casual speech to mean *never*, or *that's all*. It sounds like he is never called any permutation of 'artist'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that placing "just" later was more idiomatic, but apparently it is not, and I agree that it is clearer this way.